# How to call non-static methods statically within the same class (not strict mode)

Tags: php, phpunit

We have a library that uses a lot of static methods. However, this has made testing in PHPUnit difficult as I cannot mock those static method calls. So, I'm in the process of removing the static keywords and gradually migrating static calls such as:

```
$users = App_Model_User::find(...);
```

..to:

```
$users = App_ServiceLocator::get('model.user')->find(...);
```

This will allow me to swap items out when testing. However, in the model library we have many statically defined methods and calls such as:

```
// method declaration
public static function find(...) {...

// method calls within the class
$result = static::find(...);
```

I started removing the static keywords from the method declarations, but I was a little unsure how to declare the method calls. I tried replacing `static` with `self` and that worked, but I don't know if this is the correct usage here. I don't want to use $this as we will be in a state where parts of our app are calling find statically, and newer parts or those that have been changed, are using the service locator:

```
public function someMethod()
{
    $result = self::find(...); // is this correct? I want to be able to call find here statically as well as when an instance without breaking things
```

By the way, we are not running in strict mode. I know strict mode is probably a good option. I took heart from Laravel as I know it is capable of the same method being called statically or as an instance method:

```
User::where(...)->get();

// $user instance passed into the controller action
$user->where(...)->get();
```

...so hopefully what I'm trying to do is not too bad a practise, I hope. Would appreciated any advice on this